# Using variables from Struts2 with ReactJS

Tags: ajax, reactjs

So here`s the deal. At my workplace, we are trying to introduce ReactJS components in our web app (JSP/Struts2 etc).

So far I've built a component that is supposed to display a tree based on an object, here's a sample:

```
export default {
    name: 'Global',
    nodeid: 99,
    toggled: true,
    children: [
        {
            name: 'Mid Node',
            nodeid:  0,
            chosen: false,
            pushed: false,
            toggled: false,
            children: [
                { name: 'Lower Node',
                  nodeid: 1,
                  chosen: false,
                  pushed: false,
                  toggled: false,
                  children: [{
                    name : "Low Child 1",
                    pushed: false,
                    toggled: false,
                    chosen:false
                  }]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

What I want to do is receive this from a struts action response, rather than having it hard coded to a file which is what I did in my example.

```
import React from 'react';
import TreeComponent from 'proj-1/TreeComponent';
import HierarchyJson from './internal/Data';

export default function ExampleTreeComponent() {
    return <TreeComponent hierarchyJson={HierarchyJson} functionMode={2} htmlId="tree1"/>
}
```

I've seen a ton of posts where spring is used, but I don't know what are my options in this case. I don't want to have to write an AJAX call to get the data after my JSP page has already rendered.

Comment: React aside, how does struts normally pass data to the browsers JS engine?

Comment: struts passes data to JSP pages thru OGNL. OGNL is able to translate variables from the action class to their value when referenced in struts tags such as s:text or s:hidden...  I had the idea of using hidden tag to store the json object representation but this seems bad. what is done is that a JS will read the data from a hidden element then use it..

Comment: JSP, OGNL, etc. are server-side technology that works with servlets and doesn't work with javascript. However, in javascript you can call these services via http.

Comment: Hi @RomanC, my idea is to have a single action call render the object in a JSP hidden tag and then read this value with ReactJS. I don`t want to have to write an HTTP call on top of the action post which already returns my desired object.

Comment: If you don't want to make HTTP call then you shouldn't use ReactJS.

Comment: What's wrong with making an HTTP call anyways?

Comment: The whole point of the change is to reduce rendering times.. the original tree component was horrible. I'm afraid an HTTP call may make the change seem pointless.